# Can't use jasmine-jquery matchers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am using Karma, Jasmine, and attempting to use some of the custom matchers jasmine-jquery provides to test some DOM manipulation I'm doing.

I have the following in my karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],
    files: [
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'src/**/*',
        '.tsout/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
        '**/*.ts',
        '**/*.json'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
       '.tsout/*.js': 'coverage'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    plugins: [
        'karma-jasmine-jquery',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-coverage'
    ],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

And, in one of my .spec.js files I have something like:

```
describe("DOM Stuffs", function(){

    it("should have a DOM element with ID test", function(){
        expect($('#test').toBeInDOM());
    });

});
```

Karma fires off with no complaints, and all of my previous tests run as expected. When it gets to this test, however, I get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: $(...).toBeInDOM is not a function at Object.<anonymous>
```

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

**Versions:** karma: 0.12.33 | jasmine: 2.1.1 | karma-jasmine: 0.3.5 | jasmine-jquery: 2.1.0 | karma-jasmine-jquery: 0.1.1

Comment: `expect($('#test').toBeInDOM());` should be `expect($('#test')[0]).toBeInDOM()`; Read the docs: https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery

Comment: It's just a typo, so I voted to close it (offtopic -> typographycal errors)

Comment: Ahh, the worst. That fixed it. Thanks for the second pair of eyes!